# Imitating a "browserLike" POST request

Tags: java, http, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to get search results from [this site](http://wordstat.yandex.com/), using `Java`'s `org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient`. I'm able to login without any problems, but when I `POST` the search request, the response I get is the same page refreshed without the search results. So I checked what and where exactly Chrome sends via it's `POST` request and configured my request the same way. Well now the response I get is one of those capture images with text that one must type to proceed(that dose not happen when searching via Chrome).

**Is there any way the server recognizes that the request was not `POST`'ed by a browser?**

Comment: It's probably looking at the `User-Agent` and/or `Referer` headers of the request.

Comment: @AndrewLambert Both of these are correctly set.